# iPad touchstart events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm using JS+jQuery to create an interactive menu supposed to work both with pc and mobile devices. The menu is created on-the-fly, so I need to use `.on()`.

I'm testing the mobile side with my iPad, my code is something like this:

```
jQuery(document).on('click touchstart','.button', function(){ /* Do... */ });
```

The `click` event works fine on my PC, but the `touchstart` doesn't do anything. Even leaving `click` or `touchstart` only it doesn't work on my iPad.

Comment: try with jQuery UI Touch Punch http://touchpunch.furf.com/ it helped me to make click events work on ipad

Comment: You said `click` doesn't work on the iPad. That means something's wrong with your code, because `click` should work fine. Can you make a demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I don't know why, but now with only `click`,  it works fine. What I had to do was rewrite `'click'` in the `.on()` function body. Mysterious behaviour. :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've definitely solved by putting `touchstart` before `click` in the `.on()` method.

Comment: Can you clarify? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Doug flip order of event names: jQuery(document).on('touchstart click','.button', function(){ /* Do... */ });

Answer (score 0):

If this does not work ..
Try associating the `event` after the element is added to the `DOM`. Check if that helps..

```
// Button appended to your DOM on the fly

$('.button').on('touchstart', function(){

});
```

Comment: My code adds the buttons to the DOM before I associate the events.

Comment: `jQuery(document).on('event', 'selector')` is delegated. So that's not the problem.

Comment: True, the one you have done is event delegation .. In general this approach should work for both PC and mobile.. So not able to comprehend why it might not be working in your case... That's the reason i suggested that you add the event after the button class in inserted into your DOM